# Is product of two compact operator on a Hilbert space is also compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let me first define the notion of the compact operator
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over a field $K$ ,An Operator $A$ is said to be compact if for every bounded sequence $x_{n}\in H$ the sequence $A(x_{n})$ contains a convergent subsequence in $H$.

My question is if $A$ and $B$ are compact operators does this implies $AB$ is also a compact Operator? If not can someone please give a counter-example? Or if true please give some hint to prove it.

Comment: Welcome on math.stackexchange. This question has been asked multiple times. Try to use the search to find old versions.

Comment: Did you try showing this directly from the definition? It's pretty straightforward. More generally, for any bounded operator $A$ on $H$ and compact operator $K$ on $H$, $AK$ and $KA$ are both compact. The compact operators are a two-sided ideal on $B(H)$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I tried it ,For any bounded sequence $x_{n}$ in $H$ ,$A(x_n)$ and $B(x_n)$ both will have a subsequence which is convergent so suppose $A(x_{ni})$ and $B(x_{nj})$ are two convergent subsequence,I am confused what to do after this.

Comment: Sourav Ghosh has basically what I was going to suggest you inspect as an answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $(x_n) $ be a bounded sequence.

Let $Tx_{n_k}\subset Tx_n$ convergent subsequence.

Convergent sequence is bounded . Hence $S(T(x_{n_k}) $ has a convergent subsequence. Hence $ST x_n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Is this a hint or a complete solution?

H.W : A compact operator on a Hilbert space can't have bounded inverse. (Hint: Riesz's lemma)